# How to create a Git attributes file

Tags: git, gitattributes

I would like to add an attributes file to my Git repository as described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes). It indicates that I should include `.gitattributes` in the root folder of my repository.

- Is `.gitattributes` simply a file or is it a folder ? How do I create this file/folder ?

  *Windows raises the following errors :*

  > **"Can't create a file without a filename"**

  > **"You must type a filename"**
- Where should one add the file ? Under the repository root, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\`, or the Git folder, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\.git\` ?
- Will the attributes be enforced for other contributors cloning/forking my repository ?

  *e.g. If I pushed to GitHub or GitLab and some other party pulled down a copy would the attributes I added be enforced upon their machine as well ?*

**Related :** [Git Ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48207907/958580)

**Note :** I'm using [TortoiseGit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseGit) and msysgit on a Windows platform if it helps.

Comment: I had this same issue about the file name, and since I am on Windows 10 (Anniversary update), I was able to use [Bash](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/) (Windows' Ubuntu subsystem) to run `mv whatever.doc .gitattributes`.

Comment: Related post - [How to create a .gitignore file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10744305/465053)

Comment: Usually on Windows I simply create such a file from a Powershell or command line (cmd)
`echo . > .gitignore`
then edit the file with Notepad.
With `git bash` touch .gitignore also works on Windows.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### **Is `.gitattributes` a file or a folder ? How do I create it ?**

- **Windows :** Create a new text file (Right click>new>text file) within windows explorer and rename it (Shortcut : `F2`) as follows

  ```
  .gitattributes.
  ```

***Note :** That is `DOT` + `gitattributes` + `DOT`, windows will remove the trailing `DOT` for you producing the appropriate filename*

- **Unix :** and it's variants (Ubuntu, Raspberrian, Mac OS etc.)

  ```
  touch .gitattributes
  ```
- **Alternatively :** Clone the [Git Attributes](https://github.com/Danimoth/gitattributes) repository and move/copy the `.gitattributes` file that is applicable to your repository (Footnote 1 and 2).

#### Where should one add the file ? Under the repository root, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\`, or the Git folder, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\.git\` ?

There are two locations where one can add the Git attributes file

```
    \Repository                        (1)
    \Repository\.git\info\attributes   (2)
```

1. Adding a `.gitattributes` file here sets the attributes "Universally".
2. Creating the `.gitattributes` file here sets the attributes "Personally", that is the repository upon one's own machine. While inadvisable you may a have [good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15090352/958580) for doing so .

#### Will the attributes be enforced for other contributors cloning/forking my repository ?

Provided the file is [committed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7080914/958580) to the repository, it will be cloned when the repository is cloned and the attributes enforced upon the machines of the the contributors of ones project accordingly (Footnote : 3 and 4).
Attributes are applied "Globally " when `.gitattributes` is added to the project root, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\.gitattributes`, and "Locally" when added to some sub-folder, `X:\PATH\TO\Repository\SOME\SUB-FOLDER\.gitattributes`.

**Footnote(s) :**

1. Some care must be taken if you are using Large File Storage (Git LFS) as these files may not be LFS aware or vice versa. Additionally LFS will create `.gitattributes` for you when you setup tracking.
2. Coincidentally there is also repository for [Git Ignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore).
3. Initially, when I first asked the question, I was concerned about the correct treatment of line endings; `.gitattributes` handles this well but it is better for each contributor to configure git properly upon their own machines.
4. Don't be the idiot that adds `.gitattributes` to the `.gitignore` file. Yes this will apply the attributes "Personally" but some one will overwrite your workaround "Globally" one day and there will be tears and hugging... a lot of hugging !!!