# How to create a .gitignore file in Windows 10

Tags: bash, git

I tried to create a .gitignore file in my repository's root directory with the command

```
$ touch .gitginore
```

in Git Bash.

[image]

But when I looked at the file from the Windows Explorer. It says it's a text document. Isn't it supposed to be of the type `File`?

[image]

Comment: What Explorer has to say is meaningless.

Comment: Try "gitignore" and ".README", and "git.ignore", "READ.ME"

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How do I manually create a file with a . (dot) prefix in Windows? For example, .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-do-i-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example)*

Comment: Only the file name is different and it still works on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`touch .gitignore` works just fine. Windows detects it as a text file but git should works perfectly.

To be sure of it, you can type `ls -la` and you should see all your files with their extensions, including `.gitignore` just like in the following picture:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please do not post terminal contents as screenshots. Paste the text directly into your answer. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: .gitignore is a text file, And the explorer of windows detect files by extension to open it, it has no impact on git.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question does not specify any required tools, this contains a solution if you want to create a `.gitignore` file using `command prompt` or `Windows Explorer`.

### Command Prompt:

In case one receives the following error message on a Windows 10 system in command prompt because `touch` is a command of git bash:

> 'touch' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

You can either use the following command in command prompt (cmd):

```
echo. > .gitignore
```

or

```
type nul > .gitignore
```

as indicated here: [Windows equivalent of 'touch' (i.e. the node.js way to create an index.html)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011267/windows-equivalent-of-touch-i-e-the-node-js-way-to-create-an-index-html). This procedure will not generate a `Text Document` as indicated in the problem statement, but a file that appears to not have any extension.

### Windows Explorer:

If you try to do it in Windows 10 Explorer by clicking right mouse button(RMB)>New>`Text Document` and you try to name it `.gitignore` you can receive the following error:

> You must type a file name.

This can be overcome by giving it the filename `.gitignore.`. So if your git repository folder contains a folder named `output` which you want to suppress/not sync, you can add it to the `.gitignore` by editing the `.gitignore.` file with a text editor and adding a line that contains `/output`. This last procedure generates a file which is also a `.txt` document as indicated in the problem statement, but as mentioned by @hobbs and @Youkool that is not a problem for git. Furthermore, the last procedure is verified in Windows 10 with `git version 2.16.1.windows.4`.

Answer (score 0):

> but when I looked at the file from the windows explorer. It says it's a text document. Isn't it supposed to be of the type File

Windows says your README is of type `File` because it has no extension. In contrast, your .gitignore file has the extension `.gitignore` which Windows has been configured to report (probably by the git-for-windows installer) the type `Text Document`.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to *[How do I manually create a file with a . (dot) prefix in Windows? For example, .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-do-i-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example)*.

Reproducing for your easy access: In File Explorer, right click anywhere and create a new file. Type the new filename as `.something.` (notice the appended period) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice, job done.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. So this is a duplicate SO question?

Comment: Yes, this question is a duplicate question (of the mentioned one, posted nearly 7 years earlier) - it still works on Windows 10. I have voted to close.