# Windows OneDrive says .gitattributes. file is an illegal filename?

Tags: git, onedrive

I'm trying to create a `.gitattribute` file on Windows 10 while storing my checkout and repo on OneDrive.  I'm trying to correct the CRLF issue with some CSVs I keep having to upload, but putting them in the repo with the CRLF makes every line in the file read as changed because the ones in the repo only have LF.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18332321/18149) you have to name the file `.gitattribute.` on windows to be able to fix the CRLF issue.

I'm using the following version of git:

```
git version 2.19.0.windows.1
```

Comment: the question you quote dates back from 2013 (granted, a comment states it still had issues in 2017). Have you tried creating a `.gitattributes` file (no dot at the end) ?

Comment: The file's name is `.gitattributes` (note the `s` at the end). The hack for Windows is to use the name `.gitattributes.` (note that this ends with `s.` not just `.`).